# Reset color aesthetic when using multiple ggplot2 geom_crossbar arguments

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I'm trying to control the color of two separate calls to `geom_crosbar`, using green for the first plot, and blue for the second plot. However, I get the warning from the second `geom_crossbar` call Scale for 'fill' is already present:

> Warning: Adding another scale for 'fill', which will replace the existing
>   scale.

Here's an example of my code:

```
   my.data %>%
   ggplot(aes(site, npp_nofert)) +
    geom_crossbar(aes(ymin=npp_nofert-npp.sd_nofert,ymax=npp_nofert+npp.sd_nofert, 
                      fatten=1.0,fill=period),position='dodge', alpha=0.5)   +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Greens") + 
    #labs(y=expression(paste("MMM %",Delta," (+/- 1",sigma,")")), x="", fill="", title="") + theme_bw() + 
    labs(y="",x="", fill="", title="") + theme_bw() + 
    theme(legend.key.size=unit(1.0,"cm"),legend.direction="horizontal",legend.position=c(0.3,0.05), 
          axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), 
          plot.title=element_text(size=12,margin=margin(t=5,b=-20)), legend.spacing=unit(0,"cm"),
          text = element_text(size=15)) + 
   new_scale_fill() +
   geom_crossbar(aes(ymin=npp_fert-npp.sd_fert,ymax=npp_fert+npp.sd_fert, fatten=1.0,fill=period), 
                 position='dodge',alpha=0.5)   +
   scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")
```

And example output:
[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot `dput()` the data as I do not have permission to do that. 
How can I set the first plot to green and second to blue? Also, just noticed the call to alpha is in the legend. How to remove that?

Notes: The 1980 to 1999 period, there is only a single plot (i.e., no treatment), so there will not be overlaying plots for that period. The x axis represents study sites, I can fix the labels later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way to go about this would be to use the `ggnewscale` package, which allows you to 'reset' an aesthetic at some point in the plotting process.

Since there is no data to use, I'll make up some dummy data that has a vague semblance to what you're showing above.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5,
  blue_low = 1:5,
  blue_mid = 2:6,
  blue_high = 3:7,
  green_low = 0:4,
  green_mid = 2:6,
  green_high = 4:8
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = 1, group = x)) +
  geom_crossbar(aes(ymin = green_low, y = green_mid, ymax = green_high, 
                    fill = as.factor(x)),
                position = "dodge", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens") +
  new_scale_fill() + # Important to put this after you defined the first scale
  geom_crossbar(aes(ymin = blue_low, y = blue_mid, ymax = blue_high, 
                    fill = paste0(x, "_blue")), # paste to differentiate scale
                position = "dodge", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I'm sure it won't be too difficult to take the `new_scale_fill()` and put it in the correct position in your plotting code, which I think is after `scale_fill_brewer(palette="Greens")`.

Comment: Great! that worked with modification to my arguments inside ggplot and geom_crossbar.

Answer (score 0):

So I've decided that the approach I was using for the plot looks terrible. A better solution, IMO, is to use geom_crossbar with geom_pointrange.

Here's an example using the data that teubrand provided:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5,
  blue_low = 1:5,
  blue_mid = 2:6,
  blue_high = 3:7,
  green_low = 0:4,
  green_mid = 2:6,
  green_high = 4:8
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = 1, group = x)) +
   geom_crossbar(aes(ymin = green_low, y = green_mid, ymax = green_high, 
                     fill = as.factor(x)),
                 position = "dodge", alpha = 0.8) +
   scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens") +
   new_scale_fill() + # Important to put this after you defined the first scale
   geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = blue_low, y = blue_mid, ymax = blue_high, 
                     fill = as.factor(x)), # paste to differentiate scale
                 position = position_dodge(width=0.9), color="gray30") +
   scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

[image]